# Migrate PostgreSQL database from Heroku to Railway

Tags: postgresql, heroku, database-migration, heroku-postgres, railway.js

I am trying to find out how to migrate my PostgreSQL database easily from Heroku to Railway. I have tried using `heroku pg:backups:capture --app APP_NAME` and `heroku pg:backups:download` with `pg_restore` and no success.

I had the error

```zsh
pg_restore: error: corrupt tar header found in PGDMP (expected 0, computed 19471) file position 512
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

```zsh
heroku login
heroku run 'pg_dump $DATABASE_URL' > <filename.sql> --app <heroku-app-name>
PGPASSWORD=$PGPASSWORD psql -h $PGHOST -U $PGUSER -p $PGPORT -d $PGDATABASE -f <filename.sql>
```

**Details:**

If you logged in successfully after running `heroku login`, `$DATABASE_URL` is read from your Heroku environment, so no need to insert the database url by hand.

`<filename.sql>`: specify any filename you like. You will use it later to import the database.

`<heroku-app-name>`: The name of your Heroku (backend) app with the Postgres database.

Provision a new PostgreSQL database in your railway project and grab `$PGPASSWORD`, `$PGHOST`, `$PGUSER`, `$PGPORT`, and `$PGDATABASE` from the Variables tab.

This is what it should look like

**Example** (with dummy credentials):

```zsh
heroku login
heroku run 'pg_dump $DATABASE_URL' > mydatabasebackup.sql --app my-heroku-backend
PGPASSWORD=hjUasj8hasA6ahsjJash -h containers-us-west-15.railway.app -U postgres  -p 6473 -W -F t -d railway mydatabasebackup.sql
```